# Check if 2 strings contain same letters at same index

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
string text1 = "abcde";
string text2 = "fgchi";
```

I want to check if the 2 strings have the same characters at the same index and if they do then let the place where they are the same be printed.

Comment: The strings have the same length?

Comment: What did you try? For instance, do you know how to get a character at a specific index?

Comment: yes they do have the same length.

Comment: Then just loop over the first string char by char and check if the same char is at the same position in the second string

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) Docomettation and code samplw that could help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++)
            if (text1[i] == text2[i])
                Console.WriteLine("Character {0} at index {1}", text1[i], i);
```

Considering your strings have the same length.

Edit: if I should not give answers to trivial tasks such as this and instead encourage the user to find it by himself, then please point out that to me. I'm new around. [I suppose it's obvious, so i'm just not gonna do it, and adjust]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following code helps. And it shouldn´t be important how long each string is with that. Maybe the string.Format isn´t needed.

```
    private string charMatch(string str_a, string str_b) 
    {
        int char_a = str_a.Count();
        int char_b = str_b.Count();
        int runs = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (char_a <= char_b) { runs = char_a; }
        else { runs = char_b; }


        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) 
        {
            if (str_a[i] == str_b[i]) 
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("Match found at {0} \n", i));
            }
        }

            return sb.ToString();
    }
```